# "Turn sharing on and off globally" - Allowed to store setting and action IDs in cookies?

Tags: facebook, cookies, facebook-opengraph

Is it allowed to store the setting for `"turn[ing] sharing on and off globally"` in a cookie without using an extra database/backend? The only problem I can see is when the cookie doesn't exist anymore (deleted by user or cookie expired), the user has to manually turn it on/off again.

The same question goes for Open Graph Activities, like Read Actions. Are they (the IDs) allowed to store in cookies so they can be removed by the user later on? That would solve the requirement

> Allow users to remove any read stories you publish to Facebook and include this option on the same page where you host the article

Simply said: Can I make use of Facebook Open Graph without a backend?

Thank you!

Comment: As for share on/off – if you make the default "off", then the user has to turn it on again if the cookie is not there, but there will be no unwanted sharing for users with no cookie. And the ID already published you can read from the API, so now need to store them.

Comment: Thank you! Do you want to post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for share on/off – if you make the default "off", then the user has to turn it on again if the cookie is not there, but there will be no unwanted sharing for users with no cookie.

And the ID of OG sharing actions already published you can read from the API, so no need to store them.